# Using PHP to track conversions with a "?ref=", then cutting off the file name?

Tags: php

Let's say I am advertising a webpage in a search platform with two different banners,
and I want to track the conversions of each banner.

If I set up the banners to point to these URLs:

> - www.domain.com/page.php?ref=banner1
> - www.domain.com/page.php?ref=banner2

1. Should I be using a `?ref=`? Or I can use any `?word=` that I want?
2. Assuming all users enter my page following their individual search query, which I currently see in my server weblog as the referrer, what would I see after such set up?
   Would the current referrer date be completely replaced by `banner1` and `banner2`? Or would it just show as the requested URL in my weblog, so I can still track the search queries?
3. I would want to have a link on my website that would contain a tag that would change according to the banner the user came from - `banner1` or `banner2`. How can I do this with PHP? I guess it should be something like:

   ```
   $orig = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
   //get rid of the filename besides the banner indicator
   $new1 = str_replace('webpage.php?ref=', '', $orig);
   ```

   But I'm not sure that the `"Script_Filename"` includes the `?ref=` in the first place.

UPDATE:

Thanks everyone this seems to work, however - what If I to get the http referrer as well, but only the search phrase part from that referrer? just like when a web log analayzer takes the full referrer but let you see what what the clean search phrase was. how can I create a PHP string that would only contain this clean phrase?

for example, the yahoo search referrer looks like:

```
http://search.yahoo.com/(bunch of strings)?p=keyword1+keyword2+keyword3&(bunch of strings)
```

how do I strip everything off besides the keywords?

Comment: **A.** Use any word you like. **B.** You will see the entire URL with the banner reference. **C.** Use `$_GET['ref']` (or whatever word you chose for A) to access the banner reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Yes, it can be any word. It doesn't matter.

B) HTTP referer is a HTTP header field that identifies the address of the webpage that linked to the resource being requested. In other words, referrer is the webpage from which the request to your webpage originated. To get the referrer in PHP, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it's not guaranteed to be correct. Since the browser sets this header, it could be spoofed easily.

C) Simply use `$_GET['ref']` to get the ID. Now you can simply use an `if` statement to check the value and do an action:

```
$var = $_GET['ref'];

if ($var == 'foo') {
    // do something
} else {
    // something else
}
```

Comment: thanks! I've updated my question, I have another one regarding the http referrer

Comment: @jayjay: Please post that as a new question. (hint: you can use `parse_url()`.

Answer (score 1):

a) you can use what you want, the name of the $_GET Parameter just defines how you can call it in your php script

b) dunno

c) well, you just have to look where the user came from - you can use the ref you used in a). Depending on that value, you modify the link.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ref']) && $_REQUEST['ref'] != '')
{
  $new1 = $_REQUEST['ref'];

   //Now Check Value
  if($new1 == 'banner1')
  {
     // Do something
  }
  if($new1 == 'banner2')
  {
     // Do something else
  }
}
```